# How to include a font .ttf using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to include a global font for my page. I downloaded a .ttf file, and included it in my CSS, but my font won't change.

Here's my code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'oswald';
    src: url('/font/oswald.regular.ttf');
}

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    font-size:100%;
    font:inherit;
    font-family: oswald;
    vertical-align:baseline
}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Can you check the Network tab in your browser's console to ensure that the font is loaded properly?

Comment: Get woff from [here](https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Oswald)

Comment: Perhaps you should try using the hosted version instead: https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Oswald - not every browser supports TrueType fonts.

Comment: Handy link for browser support for ttf fonts https://caniuse.com/ttf at time of posting 98.4% of browsers supported it

Answer (score 322, accepted):

Only providing .ttf file for webfont won't be good enough for cross-browser support. The best possible combination at present is using the combination as :

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

This code assumes you have .eot , .woff , .ttf and svg format for you webfont. To automate all this process , you can use : [Transfonter.org](https://transfonter.org).

Also , modern browsers are shifting towards .woff font , so you can probably do this too :

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('myfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+ */
         url('myfont.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Chrome 4+, Firefox 3.5, Opera 10+, Safari 3—5 */
}
```

Read more here : http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

---

**Look for browser support : [Can I Use fontface](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface)**

Comment: and if you're using GFonts check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/30585464/1727470

Comment: For those like me who get confused easily - paths are with forward slashes `url('path/to/font.woff')`

Comment: I had an issue with comments in the font-face rule.  Moving the comments to the end of the rule fixed the problem.

Comment: I found that the font I wanted to generate a web font for was blacklisted from Font Squirrel. However, https://transfonter.org/ worked for me.

Comment: I also had trouble with Font Squirrel. success with font-converter.net

Comment: AFAIK there's no reason to have both `woff` and `ttf`, since they're both the same format except `woff` includes compression - and all browsers that support `ttf` also support `woff`. Either use one or the other.

Comment: I have EOT only and tranfosrter.org usage is "click the Add font(s) button, select the TTF, OTF, WOFF, WOFF2 or SVG fonts on your computer and click Convert." 

Answer (score 64):

Did you try format?

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'The name of the Font Family Here';
  src: URL('font.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Read this article: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Also, might depend on browser as well.

Answer (score 30):

You can use font face like this:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family:"Name-Of-Font";
  src: url("yourfont.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

Answer (score 18):

I know this is an old post but this solved my problem.

```css
@font-face{
  font-family: "Font Name";
  src: url("../fonts/font-name.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

notice `src:url("../fonts/font-name.ttf");` we use two periods to go back to the root directory and then into the fonts folder or wherever your file is located.

hope this helps someone down the line:) happy coding

Answer (score 2):

Check the console to make sure the resource is loaded. Depending on file and folder structure, your url may be wrong. Notice the difference between:

```
src: url('/VT323/VT323-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');

src: url('VT323/VT323-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');

src: url('../VT323/VT323-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
```

Answer (score 0):

It just looks like a typo to me in the following CSS. I just tried it for myself in my CSS as I was also trying to use a font from a downloaded ttf file.

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
font-size:100%;
font:inherit;
font-family: oswald;
vertical-align:baseline
```

}

Your font-family variable has a typo oswald should be surrounded by either single or double quotes like so... `font-family: "oswald";` it should then change your text in the html. The `format: (truetype)` is not needed for your code to work properly.

Comment: You don't need quotes if the family name doesn't include whitespace.