# Google Font API uses browser detection. How to get all font variations for font-face

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, google-font-api

I just discovered that Google Font API uses browser detection

This means that when you open http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Racing+Sans+One it will show the content needed **only for your current browser**

So I can't just grab that and use in my own font-face, if I want it to work in all browsers. Many people do this, not knowing it then won't work everywhere

What would be the method to get all variations of the font? woff2/woff/ttf/etc.? (to use as fallbacks in font-face)

I just tried opening that api page in Chrome, changing browser useragent spoofing in Developer, and go through the variations. I see at least 4

Is woff2/woff/ttf enough, or how many versions do I need to be safe? Do I need EOT/SVG version too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try downloading atleast these variations of the webfonts : eot , woff , ttf , svg and then you can use them like this for maximum cross browser benefits :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

See this answer for more information: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990554/how-to-include-a-font-ttf-using-css/24990647#24990647)

Comment: Yes, that's what I came about too. My aim was to have a local fallback for the font after all that. Then I realized that using Google font as it is, is actually fine for now (and fast and simple).. But thanx ;)

Comment: At this point you really only need woff2 and woff. Browsers that do not at least support woff either do not support webfonts at all or are very old browsers full of security issues.

Answer (score 16):

The right answer is, use this website by MajoDev:

https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/

It generates the CSS for all browsers and lets you download the files for self-hosting Google font files. Works great!

Comment: This is a wonderful tool! If you have been fooling around with the source of google web fonts trying to download the correct woff, eof and svg files, look no further. I've needed this tool for years.

Answer (score 14):

Using Open Sans as an example.

http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans

Make requests with different user agents to see the different fonts: .eot, .woff, woff2, .ttf, .svg

**For .eot use these user agents:**

```
IE8
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.4; InfoPath.2; SV1; .NET CLR 3.3.69573; WOW64; en-US)

IE7
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; en-US)

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3fY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.eot);
}
```

**For .woff2 use these user agents:**

```
Firefox 36.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3VtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format('woff2'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3T8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');
}
```

**For .woff use these user agents:**

```
Safari 6.0
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25

Internet Explorer 11.0
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible, MSIE 11, Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko

Internet Explorer 10.0
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)

Internet Explorer 9.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 9.0; en-US))

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3bO3LdcAZYWl9Si6vvxL-qU.woff) format('woff');
}
```

**For .ttf use these user agents:**

```
Safari 5.0.5
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8; de-at) AppleWebKit/533.21.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.5 Safari/533.21.1

Safari 3.1
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X 10_5_2; en-gb) AppleWebKit/526+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.1 iPhone

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3SZ2oysoEQEeKwjgmXLRnTc.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

**I found another .ttf when trying other user agents. Not sure what the difference is.**

```
Safari 4.1
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-en) AppleWebKit/533.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.1 Safari/533.16

Firefox 5.0
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux) Gecko Firefox/5.0

Firefox 3.5.9
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; et; rv:1.9.1.9) Gecko/20100315 Firefox/3.5.9

Safari 3.1.1
Mozilla/5.0 (Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 2_0_1 like Mac OS X; fr-fr) AppleWebKit/525.18.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.1.1 Mobile/5G77 Safari/525.20

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3aCWcynf_cDxXwCLxiixG1c.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

**For .svg use these user agents:**

```
Safari 4.0.4
Mozilla/5.0(iPad; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B314 Safari/531.21.10gin_lib.cc

Safari 3.0
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1C25 Safari/419.3

Safari 3.0
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543 Safari/419.3

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/l/font?kit=cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3Zbd9NUM7myrQQz30yPaGQ4#OpenSans) format('svg');
}
```

**Which font formats are supported in which browsers?**

1. http://caniuse.com/#search=eot
2. http://caniuse.com/#search=ttf
3. http://caniuse.com/#search=svg
4. http://caniuse.com/#search=woff
5. http://caniuse.com/#search=woff2

Comment: As of now, woff and woff2 covers all bases, basically. Except for Opera Mini, but that browser doesn't support anything.

Comment: Using this approach I was able to generate styles with ttf fonts. This allowed me to fix search feature in PDF files generated from html in browsers. With woff2 font search does't work.