# CSS font-face not working for ttf

Tags: css, font-face

I am using @font-face like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: DINPro;
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url(../res/fonts/DINPro-Bold.otf) format("opentype");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: DINPro;
    src: url(../res/fonts/DINPro-Regular.otf) format("opentype");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: DFLiHei;
    src: url(../res/fonts/DFLiHei-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}
h1{
    font-family: DFLiHei !important;
}
```

But not working.
My folder structure is likely:

```
/index.html
/css/style.css
/res/fonts/DINPro-Bold.otf
/res/fonts/DINPro-Regular.otf
/res/fonts/DFLiHei-Regular.ttf
```

Therefore, I think wrong directory is not my problem.
Also, not only fail in special browser, but also in chrome and mobile.
Any idea?

Comment: Try to remove the second font-family, or the two first. Just for test

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include a font .ttf using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990554/how-to-include-a-font-ttf-using-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert `ttf` to `woff` format

[Try this](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: DFLiHei;
    src: url(../res/fonts/DFLiHei-Regular.woff) format('woff');
}
```

It will work in all browsers