# font-family: “ITC Avant Garde Gothic” not working in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a text from an image whose font-family is "ITC Avant Garde Gothic"

I tried putting this font-family in my CSS but unfortunately I cant see any change.

I am wondering, do I need to add something else in my CSS for the working of font-family.

The CSS code which I have is:

```
{
  font-size: 7.433px;
  font-family: "ITC Avant Garde Gothic";
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  line-height: 2.348;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transform: matrix( 1.81893039778896,0,0,1.8236290753447,0,0);
  -webkit-transform: matrix( 1.81893039778896,0,0,1.8236290753447,0,0);
  -ms-transform: matrix( 1.81893039778896,0,0,1.8236290753447,0,0);
  position: absolute;
  left: 45.265px;
  top: 181.274px;
  z-index: 127;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include a font .ttf using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990554/how-to-include-a-font-ttf-using-css)

Comment: do you have the `@font-face` in your css that directs the location of the font in your folder?

Comment: You can install the font on your system and you'll see it. Unfortunately most of your users won't so instead you need to get a web version of the font to import.

Comment: Do you have this font installed on your system?

Comment: @threeFatCat No. How can we use @font-face which will make `font-family: "ITC Avant Garde Gothic";` work ?

Comment: @threeFatCat Should I include this ?

`@font-face 
{
font-family: ITC Avant Garde Gothic;
 src: url(ITC Avant Garde Gothic.woff);
}`

Comment: @shortcut which ITC Avant GardeGothic font are you using.. there's loads of versions> you should point the url to the uploaded font on your server or one online

Comment: @shortcut sorry for late respone, please refer to Marcos Pérez Gude link. For cross-compatibility of your font I believe you shoud have atleast three types of the same font. `ttf`, `otf` and `woff`. And the `@font-face` should direct precisely the location of your font. (e.g. /source/fonts/..your font name).  But practically if it is possible look for a free "similar style" which is hosted online fonts (e.g Google fonts) and then you just need to include it in the `<head>` part of your `html` and also Google fonts will provide you the `@font-face` code for your css

Comment: It's easy. Get the TTF file, convert with an online tool like this: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ttf+converter , then copy the CSS source on the duplicated flag link and edit the paths to the font files, and you can use now the font. Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144000/using-custom-fonts-using-css . This question should be closed as duplicated tons of times.