# How can I add a local font in Blazor?

Tags: fonts, blazor-webassembly

Currently, I add the font Source Sans Pro via `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">` but this cannot load the font when the user is offline. So, I would like to add the font as local resource but I cannot make it work. Here is what I tried:

1. Delete above `<link ...>`.
2. Add `<link href="css/source-sans-pro/css/source-sans-pro.css" rel="stylesheet" />` to `<head></head>`.
3. Add file "source-sans-pro.css" to "wwwroot/css/source-sans-pro/css/" with content

   ```
   @font-face {
   font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
   src: url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf');
   }
   ```
4. Download font from [here](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro) and add it to "css/source-sans-pro/font/".

Unfortunately, the font is not Source Sans Pro. What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you are missing is to add a format to the URL property and you have fonts plural in your path, and its singular where you said you uploaded font, so I am not sure if the mistake exists in your project or its only here.

```
src: url('../font/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
```

[How to include a font .ttf using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990554/how-to-include-a-font-ttf-using-css)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was the typo with the path "fonts" vs. "font". With the correct path it even works without the `format('truetype')`. So, what is this even for?

Comment: They say : To provide the browser with a hint as to what format a font resource is — so it can select a suitable one — it is possible to include a format type inside a format() function.   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

I guess its not needed and the explanation is pretty bland, as its too often the case on why something like that is doing.