# How to change default font in .NET MAUI Blazor project?

Tags: css, .net, fonts, blazor, maui

I have a default Visual Studio project for .NET MAUI Blazor app (building for Windows x64). I've tried 2 different ways of changing the font.

1. In MauiProgram.cs there is a configuration of fonts `ConfigureFonts`. I've added a new font Montserrat-Regular.ttf to the Resources/Fonts directory and registered my font there. Using this font with its new alias didn't work though.
2. Following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73021832/how-can-i-add-a-local-font-in-blazor) I've added the same file to `wwwroot/css` and this to `wwwroot/css/app.css`

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    src: url('Montserrat-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}

html, body {
    font-family: Montserrat;
}
```

It doesn't work either. Even though changing font-family to a basic font like Arial or Times-New-Roman does in fact work.

Comment: Your style may be overwritten. Use F12 to check the style of the current style file, and then change it.

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT I don't think it is, since changing the font to Arial or TimesNewRoman 
 within app.css does work. It only doesn't see the custom font

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a project and tested the code you provided. You should add your own .ttf file to wwwroot/css/open-iconic/font/fonts directory. Just like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: `LaBelleAurore-Regular`;
    src: url('../css/open-iconic/font/fonts/LaBelleAurore-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}

html, body {
    font-family: LaBelleAurore-Regular;
}
```

If you want to put .ttf file in another folder, remember to change `url('....')` to the correct path.

Comment: it does work! I'm now wondering - why does it work only in this specific folder? When putting it even in the parent directory it stops working. I will investigate that

Comment: @Rasmond I tried to put it in the parent directory folder, and it worked. Did you change `url('.....')` to the correct path?

Comment: you're right, it works ;) rebuild actually helped here

Comment: if you could add that to your answer it would be perfect