# Cannot change default font in .NET MAUI Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

It seems that it is impossible to include the downloaded font (e.g. any from Google) via CSS in a MAUI Blazer project!

I refer to the following post: [How to change default font in .NET MAUI Blazor project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74680546/how-to-change-default-font-in-net-maui-blazor-project/75863500#75863500)

I wrote this in the post there, but I was told to open a new post.

I have written about this in detail in the following post:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1193613/change-font-in-maui-blazor

There is also a project on GitHub with which you can reproduce the problem:
https://github.com/true-perfect-code/MauiApp1_LocalFont

Is it possible that something has changed in MAUI or WebView2 in the meantime?

I would be very grateful if someone could confirm my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample project, you have the URL incorrectly set for the font (and a double `@` symbol for some reason)

What you currently have in `index.html`

```css
@@font-face {
  font-family: "Comfortaa Light";
  src: url("../css/open-iconic/font/fonts/Comfortaa.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

What you should have (one `@` for `font-face` and one `.` at the start of `src`):

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Comfortaa Light";
  src: url("./css/open-iconic/font/fonts/Comfortaa.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

Looks like this when those changes are made:

[image: Hello World!]